# C# WebClient DownloadData issue on double quotes

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient

Im making a request to a url, but in the returned string i get foreach " an \"

This is my code:

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
byte[] databuffer = webclient.DownloadData(url);
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(databuffer);
```

What could be the problem to return as content of the webpage for instance:

`<div id=\"whatever\">` instead `<div id="whatever">`?

Comment: If you want to use the HTML in some way, consider this parser for the job: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: You're looking from the debugger, don't you? If you print it to Console you'll see the _plain_ version. If you look in debug mode, quotes, backslashes, ... are escaped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem, you are probably looking the result in Visual Studio Debugger which does this. The actual string you are getting doesn't have any `\"`. Try saving it to a file and you will see:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test.htm", databuffer);
```

So no worries, unless the web page you are downloading is crap and is using `\"` instead of `"` in the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After 10 minutes, i will set this as best answer :-)